# Honey-glazed gammon (ham) - What to serve with it?

Tags: pairing, ham

I've got down a pretty good honey/whiskey glazed gammon but previously I've always used it cold in sandwhiches or on meat platters.

This evening, however, I am planning on serving the joint hot as part of a main meal.

I'm out of inspiration regarding what sides to serve with it.  I was going to go with a selection of steamed vegetables but would these also need a sauce/gravy?

So, in short, what would work well with hot gammon with a sweet glaze?

I know we don't like questions that solicit opinion so I'll add that I need some proven pairings with reasons why the different flavours, sweetness, acidity etc of the ingredients work.

Comment: Although you mentioned that the community doesn't like poll questions, I still downvoted and voted to close as such.

Comment: @Mien A Bot added that! It should be "acceptable" now, otherwise why does SA bother with the Bot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ireland boiled or glazed ham is a staple.  Traditionally it's had with cut up cabbage (ideally you would cook the cabbage in the same water the ham was boiled in as this gives it lovely flavour) but you could just cut it up and pan fry it with a little butter.  Normally it would be served with boiled floury potatoes.  Traditionally (in Ireland) you wouldn't have a sauce with it but a parsely sauce (as stated in the other reply would be lovely) or simply serve with some strong mustard or a brown sharp sauce such as HP.

You could also shred the ham and serve it with noodles in a hot broth with some shredded cabbage and other vegetables.

The ham is going to be centre of attention - salty, rich with a sweetness.  The cabbage and potato are happy bedfellows as the cabbage cuts through the saltyness/sweetness.  You don't want strong flavours competing with the ham and neither cabbage or potato will.

Answer (score 2):

Parsley sauce is a traditional English accompaniment to ham. Simply infuse milk with parsley stalks, onion, and bay leaf, then strain and use the milk to make a white sauce (i.e. with a roux) and add chopped fresh parsley leaves at the end. It works very well.

Comment: Thanks.  How will that sauce work well with the sweet/whiskey of the ham glaze?  How will it sit on the palette and how would the whole thing sit together?  I should stress that I'm not debating, just looking for more information should there be more answers to choose from.  Thanks again.

Comment: I believe the idea of the sauce is that the fresh, green taste of the parsley compliments the salty, slightly sweet ham. It should work well with the glaze. The sauce, being roux based, is relatively rich. It's a good autumn dish I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed greens, mac & cheese, candied yams & corn bread muffins.  Iced lemon/orange tea; (third parts tea, lemon juice, orange juice.)

Answer (score 0):

Fried potatoes (my favorite is Yukon Golds) topped with kosher salt would make a nice contrast both in flavor – the lighter taste of potato and the salt – against the sweetness of the ham glaze, and also in texture – the crispy potato slices against the smoother, softer baked ham.

Yes, the ham by nature is a bit salty, but with your sweet, multi-flavored glaze it would be a different salt experience than the crunchiness of salted fried potatoes.

A cold, crisp green salad would provide a third element in both taste and contrast. Rather than dressing the salad before serving, maybe offer two or three different options at the table, with which guests can dress their own salad portions.

Both of these are simple, inexpensive, relatively quick preparations, yet add a lot to the very delicious sounding ham glaze you describe without upstaging it. This would also leave you with two different non-meat choices should you get blindsided by an unannounced vegetarian.

Answer (score 0):

A baked potato & onion sauce with mixed peppers. Make the onion sauce in the usual way & just before serving stir in chopped red, green & yellow peppers. They should be warmed through but still lovely & crispy.
Valerie